# Consumption of an exponentially growing population

Tags: integration

Given that a population (eg. of bacteria) grows exponentially with the function

$$p 2^{\frac{t}{10}}$$

where $p$ is the initial population and $t$ is the time in minutes. Given that the population consumes (eg. food) at a steady rate, how would you calculate how much the population consumes?

Assume that each bacterium consumes $1µg$ of food per minute, how much food would an initial population of **100** bacteria have consumed after 10 minutes? The solution lies somewhere between the consumption of 100 and 200 bacteria over 10 minutes, thus between $1000µg$ and $2000µg$.

I figured I needed an integral to solve this problem. If I'm not mistaken, the integral of the function above is:

$$\int_0^{10} p 2^{\frac{t}{10}} dt = \frac{10 p 2^{\frac{t}{10}}}{\ln{2}}$$

For $p=100$ the result is $2885.39µg$, which is higher than the expected maximum of $2000µg$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: +1 for showing what you had done, allowing svenkatr to give a useful response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a definite integral

$\int_{0}^{10} p 2^{\frac{t}{10}} dt = \left[ \frac{10p2^{\frac{t}{10}}}{ln 2} \right]_{0}^{10} = \frac{10p}{ln2} = 1442.69 \mu g $ of food consumed.

Comment: It looks like you just forgot to subtract the value at the lower limit.

Comment: I've subtracted the value at the lower limit in my answer. Stijn Van Bael had omitted that in his calculations.

Comment: yes, I forgot to put in the @Stijn Van Bael.  Sorry